# Why was my "not an answer" flag rejected?

Tags: discussion, flagging

I've flagged [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1311775/427317) as not an answer and my flag was rejected. Why?

I think that answer was posted as a joke, and it did not attempt to answer the question.

---

**Update** for those who can't see deleted posts:

Question: [Are M-disks truly more reliable than other forms of storage?](https://superuser.com/questions/1106325/are-m-disks-truly-more-reliable-than-other-forms-of-storage/1311775#1311775)

Answer: [image]

Comment: Thanks for posting this.  I was going to create a Meta question related to the exact same scenario.  I flagged that same post as `not an answer` but later discovered it in my history with the following narrative:  `declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it`.  Needless to say, I was very surprised!

Comment: Thank the deleter for this action so that we no onger must endure a spelling error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It got deleted. By the looks of things it had spam flags *and* NAA flags, and I suspect that when the spam flag was dismissed so were the others.

So, yeah, the flag was valid, the post deleted, and the flag handling UI's kind of to blame here I suspect.

Comment: As of a few years ago, it's no longer the case that mods have to dismiss all pending flags with the same outcome. So it *must* have been the case that the mod handling the flag pressed the wrong button.

Comment: Erm. It happens still. Occasionally to our annoyance. You can selectively dismiss or accept flags but accidentally all the flags happens

Comment: Meh, a single declined flag isn't a problem.

Comment: I get this all the time and it is quite frustrating when your flag is valid but now it is marked in your history as a declined, they should fix the interface or make sure the procedure is consistent.